# How to get metrics of Secret Manager

Tags: google-secret-manager

From looking at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp it seems like there is currently (2020-07-29) no way of retrieving e.g. Key ages in Metrics.

So currently it seems like I would be forced to have a scheduled Cloud function which manually reads the SecretManager API and pushes the data into Stackdriver.

Or is there an easier way to get Metrics for SecretManager?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: E.g. a Dashboard where you can see how often certain Keys were used and their age.

Comment: Thanks! Dashboarding and reporting is on our radar, but I'll check with the team. Instead of a Cloud Function, you could use Cloud Asset Inventory. You could also create metrics based on secret manager audit logs; here's an example from the KMS docs: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/monitoring